# Wordpress cannot find "civicrm/a/#/hello" for angular js extension module

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, civicrm, civicrm-extension

Am new to Civicrm. I've followed the instructions on this video to setup angularJs modules https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_nKAk7vg80. The problem is the base route for civicrm angularjs pages is not found.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am new to civicrm as well and I am also stuck at same problem..